# Generic class registry for command and handler in Java with Micronaut

Tags: java, generics, java-8, java-11, micronaut

Trying to do the dependency injection of java generics class in Micronaut

Interface

```
public interface IRequestHandler<C, R> {
    R handler(C c);
}
```

Dependency Injection

```
@Singleton
public record ServiceBus(IRequestHandler<C, R> iRequestHandler) implements IServiceBus{

    @Override
    public <C, R> R send(C c) {
        return iRequestHandler.handler(c);
    }
}
```

Interface

```
public interface IServiceBus {
    <C,R> R send(C c);
}
```

Implementation

```
public class ProductController {
    public ProductController(IServiceBus iRequestHandler){
        _iserviceBus= iRequestHandler;
    }
     public Mono<?> get(ProductSearchCriteriaCommand searchCriteria) {
            var item = _iserviceBus.<CreateProductCommand,CreateProductCommand>send(new CreateProductCommand());
            return null;
        }
}
```

Problem for me is on ServiceBus class, how can I pass the type for `public record ServiceBus(IRequestHandler<C, R> iRequestHandler)` and `iRequestHandler.handler(c);`

[image]

```
@Singleton
public class CreateProductCommandHandler implements IRequestHandler<CreateProductCommand, CreateProductCommand> {
    @Override
    public CreateProductCommand handler(CreateProductCommand createProductCommand) {
        return null;
    }
}

@Singleton
public record DeleteProductCommandHandler() implements IRequestHandler<DeleteProductCommand,DeleteProductCommand> {

    @Override
    public DeleteProductCommand handler(DeleteProductCommand deleteProductCommand) {
        return null;
    }
}
```

When I am calling `_iserviceBus.<CreateProductCommand,CreateProductCommand>send(new CreateProductCommand());` in controller I am trying to invoke `handler` method in `CreateProductCommandHandler` class

Similarly if I call `_iserviceBus.<CreateProductCommand,CreateProductCommand>send(new DeleteProductCommand());` the `handler` method of `DeleteProductCommandHandler` class should get invoke

Comment: What is `C` in the record declaration? (Records can be generic. Yours is not.)

Comment: C will be either CreateProductCommand or UpdateProductCommand or DeleteCommand

Comment: In `IServiceBus` is `<C,R> R send(C c)` the same as `Object send(Object o)`?

Comment: @JeffScottBrown The equivalent of <C,R> R send(C c) is  < CreateProductCommand, ResponseCreateProduct> ResponseCreateProduct send (CreateProductCommand createProductCommand)

Comment: Given the way your code is written, it isn't clear to me how the compiler could figure that out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You incorrectly defined IServiceBus interface:

```
public interface IServiceBus {
    <C,R> R send(C c);
}
```

should be:

```
public interface IServiceBus<C,R> {
    R send(C c);
}
```

UPD. Very basic example of registry.

```
public interface IRequestHandler<C, R> {

    R handler(C c);

    Class<C> getCmdType();
    
}

public class ServiceBus implements IServiceBus {

    private final Map<Class<?>, IRequestHandler<?, ?>> handlerMap;

    public ServiceBus(List<IRequestHandler<?, ?>> handlers) {
        handlerMap = handlers.stream()
                .collect(toMap(
                        IRequestHandler::getCmdType,
                        Function.identity()
                ));
    }

    @Override
    public <C, R> R send(C c) {
        IRequestHandler<C, R> handler = (IRequestHandler<C, R>) handlerMap.get(c.getClass());
        if (handler == null) {
            throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Unsupported command: " + c.getClass());
        }
        return handler.handler(c);
    }

}
```

Comment: It's not the only mistake. The record is not generic as well.

Comment: Isn't `ServiceBus` also going to have to change?

Comment: I can't define IServiceBus as class generics, because I need to create Class types 3 times in one controller. IServiceBus<CreateProductCommand, CreateProductResponse> and IServiceBus<UpdateProductCommand, CreateProductResponse> and IServiceBus<DeleteProductCommand, CreateProductResponse>. I was trying to do something like this _iserviceBus.<CreateProductCommand,CreateProductResponse>send(new CreateProductCommand()); _iserviceBus.<UpdateProductCommand,CreateProductResponse>send(new CreateProductCommand()), _iserviceBus.<DeleteProductCommand,CreateProductResponse>send(new CreateProductCommand())

Comment: @SanJaisy it is not clear what is your goal: if you have different request handlers which accept different commands and produce different responses you need to create a "registry" of such handlers which picks up the most suitable one and delegates the job to it (most probably you also need to generify command type by response type), at current moment the existence of IServiceBus seems to be pointless: it is doing nothing.

Comment: @AndreyB.Panfilov Yes I am trying to register CreateProductCommand with CreateProductCommandHandler and UpdateProductCommand with UpdateProductCommandHandler and DeleteProductCommand with DeleteProductCommandHandler and based on the command the handler method should get invoke. Quite not sure how can I do that

Comment: @AndreyB.Panfilov can you please show an example to create a "registry" of such handlers which picks up the most suitable one and delegates the job to it (most probably you also need to generify command type by response type)

Comment: please check upd

Comment: @AndreyB.Panfilov Thanks what would be the implementation for Class<C> getCmdType(); ?

Comment: @AndreyB.Panfilov I tried default Class<C> getCmdType(){
        return (Class<C>) this.getClass();
    }; This returns the Handler class, instead of Command class. How do I get the command class from getCmdType method

Comment: I am surprised that this works.  Where is the type information for `C` and `R` coming from in the `ServiceBus` class posted in the solution?  As far as I can tell, those generic parameters have no impact on the behavior of this code.

Comment: getCmdType() must return class of command, not class of handler

Comment: Thanks @AndreyB.Panfilov now it is working fine 
    public Class getCmdType() {
        return SomeCommandType.class;
    }